# Understanding Evaluation Mapping

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

I have a question about the definition of an evaluation mapping:

We define an evaluation map from a topological space $X$ to the product of real numbers $\prod_\alpha \mathbb{R}$ to be $h: X \to \prod_\alpha \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha \in A$ an arbitrary index set, such that $h(x)_\alpha = f_\alpha(x)$.

To my understanding, an arbitrary product space can essentially be treated as a collection of functions mapping from the index set to the set factor spaces. In our case, this means that $\prod_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{R} \equiv \{ t: A \to \mathbb{R} \}$. In particular, this means that we have $h(x) = t_x \in \prod_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{R}$ to be a **function**. Moreover, we have $f_\alpha(x) = h(x)_\alpha = \pi_\alpha(h(x)) = \pi_\alpha(t_x) = t_x(\alpha)$. This implies that we have $f_\alpha(x) = t_x(\alpha)$ for any given $\alpha \in A$ and $x \in X$. This is where I am a little bit confused. What exactly is relation between these two objects? Are the literally equivalent? It seems like they are "duals" of each other but I can't put my figure on it.

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have (presumably) some set of functions $f_\alpha: X \to \Bbb R$ where $\alpha$ ranges over some index set $A$.

The set $P:=\prod_{\alpha \in A} \Bbb R$ indeed is the set of **all** functions from $A$ to $\Bbb R$. So an element of $P$ is just a function. But I think part of the confusion lies in the fact that if $g \in P$ authors use the notation $g_\alpha$ and $g(\alpha)$ *interchangeably*. They mean exactly the same though: the value of $g$ at $\alpha$. The first notation is more "product"-like (like sequence indices if we the functions we defined on $\Bbb N$), the second more "pure", just function-notation.

The evaluation function $h:X \to P$ is just the function that maps $h(x)$ for some $x \in X$ (now constant for a moment) to a function $h(x) \in P$; in order to define that function we have to define its values at every $\alpha \in A$ and this is done in an obvious way:

$$h(x)(\alpha)=f_\alpha(x) \text{ or in the other notation: } h(x)_\alpha = f_\alpha(x)$$

So either way you're just defining the function $h(x)$ for temporily fixed $x \in X$. With $\alpha$ we only have the function $f_\alpha$ from our family at our disposal and with a point $x$ and a function, what else could you do but evaluate that function in that point?

Hope this helps. It's indeed just a function notation in a different form. It's good to be aware of it as many texts use this.